# How to install grafana-cli and grafana plugin

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to install [Simple JSON plugin](https://grafana.net/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource) which needs `grafana-cli`.

But my Terminal says `command not found`. Can someone please help how to install `grafana-cli` and `grafana plugin`

OS - Mac, grafana v3.0

Comment: How did you install Grafana? The bin directory where the grafana-cli executable is located should be in your path.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but for me I found it using

`ps -ef | grep grafana`

To find the location of grafana (which was /usr/sbin/grafana) and grafana-cli was there too. That dir is only in the path for the root user so switching to root (sudo su) solved the issue also.

Answer (score 1):

for S.O windows, you need add manually the path of grafana-cli.exe to environment variables.
follow this steps.

1. open control panel.
2. select the option "system".
3. select option "advanced features"
4. select environment variables,
5. on variables of user select the row "path", select the button edit
6. add your path of grafana-cli.exe.
7. save changes.
8. open a new cmd terminal.
9. write `grafana-cli` and console return view of help of grafana cli commands

you can find grafana-cli  on c:/programfiles/grafanalasbs/grafana/bin

Answer (score 0):

grafane-cli is not present in 2.6.0 package. So i suppose you should build grafana from scratch or get an older version.